# Array of strings adding commas when inserted into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a bunch of names I'm adding to an array:

```
for (const approve of requestApproval[strings.Approve]) {
    approved.push(
        approve.Title + '<br/>'
    );
}
```

The array:

[image]

I then put it into an email as HTML:

```
<center>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style = "border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th>Approved</th>
            <th>Abstained</th>
            <th>Not Approved</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">${approved}</td>
            <td align="center">${abstained}</td>
            <td align="center">${disapproved}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

The result is a comma is inserted from somewhere:

[image]

How can I either stop the comma or remove the comma?

Comment: `approved.join("")` - the comma is there because its the default behavior of `Array.toString()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this in your template literal:

```
<td align="center">${approved}</td>
```

... you silently convert the array `approved` to a string, whereby the array elements are delimited with a comma.

To avoid that, either:

1. don't build an array, but a string:

   ```
   let approved = ""; // string!
   for (const approve of requestApproval[strings.Approve]) {
       approved += approve.Title + '<br/>';
   }
   ```

   Or
2. convert the array in a controlled way, using the empty string as delimiter:

   ```
   <td align="center">${approved.join("")}</td>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your array to a string by joining it with empty strings (`.join('')`), otherwise, JavaScript will automatically join it with commas when converting it to a string.

You can also replace your `for loop` with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const approved = requestApproval[strings.Approve].map(x => x.Title + '<br/>').join('');
```

or (but removes the last `<br>`):

```
const approved = requestApproval[strings.Approve].map(x => x.Title).join('<br/>');
```

Then insert the string in your html template string:

```
<td align="center">${approved}</td>
```